# Does Google Charts have TypeScript definition file(s)?

Tags: typescript, google-visualization

I want to use Google Charts with TypeScript, but I'm not sure if Google Charts has .d.ts file(s). Does anyone know if they're out there available for download and if yes, can you link them?

Comment: Might be of interest: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/15835

Comment: thanks but that's for angular google chart and I'm not using Angular I'm using React

Comment: I believe the project is merely an angular wrapper, but there is a typings file in that repository: https://github.com/angular-google-chart/google-chart-typings/blob/master/google-chart.d.ts - it doesn't seem to be related to angular in particular.

Comment: oh, that's awesome, thanks....have you used it personally? do you have an idea of how complete it is?

Comment: Sorry, no - I haven't actually used it; though it's the only result I could find. Might be worth while contacting the author and asking how complete it is, and seeing if it's possible to have it pulled into the DefinitelyTyped repository for others

Comment: The repository description says "very incomplete and work in progress"...perhaps I should look into other charting libraries

Answer (score 8):

It does (at least nowadays), called `google.visualization`:

```
npm install @types/google.visualization
```

Comment: still up to date?

Comment: I added that and still get 
**[lint] [tsc] src/pages/charts.tsx:23:18 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'.**

Comment: you need to add "google.visualization" to tsconfig.app.json compilerOptions -> types array

Comment: @TheViralGriffin I tried with this but it still gives me this error: `.../@types/google.visualization/index.d.ts' is not a module.`

Answer (score 0):

You can see them on github:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/google.visualization

You can download index.d.ts file

Comment: how to add this to file so that google var is recognised?

    **google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'bar'] });**

Comment: install @types/google.visualization and add "google.visualization" to tsconfig.app.json compilerOptions -> types array