# Property 'charts' does not exist on type 'typeof google' (Google Charts in Angular4)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, oop, google-visualization

I've implemented google-charts in Angular4 with reference to following link:

https://developers.google.com/chart/

Though chart is rendering properly and getting pie chart, but Type-Script compilation is showing error due to which project cannot be uploaded to server (deployment issues).

In index.js I have included respective file. In abc.ts (typeScript file) I even tried using

```
public google: any;
```

or

```
let google: any;
```

But, still cannot remove this error. Can someone help me out. I do not want to install with npm-package or get any newer version as all work for pie-chart will go waste or will need alternation.

index.html

[image]

abc.ts

[image]
[image]

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Assume that your compilation error is fixed somehow. Do you think your code `google.visualization.arrayTodata(temp)` will work by declaring `public google : any`? No it won't, because there is no way to tell that `google` is an instance or reference to `google-charts`. That is why compiler is giving a strict warning or error.

Comment: Just install the type declaration files as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44170660), found by a [web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=google+charts+typescript).